# I can't see module files in style library list

Tags: sharepoint

When my web part is deployed with visual studio or when I install the wsp in test environment, I don't see the module file in the list  sharepointServer/Style%20Library/Indices/CSS

But I can access to the file if I type the file name (for example sharepointServer/Style%20Library/Indices/CSS/commonStyle.css).

Elements.xml sample :

```
<Module Name="Module_Indices" Url="Style Library">

    <File Path="Module_Indices\Indices\CSS\commonStyle.css" Url="Watson_Indices/CSS/commonStyle.css" />

</Module>
```

An idea why I can't see the module files ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer [this MSDN Article and Comment in there](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms441170%28v=office.14%29.aspx) You will need to add  **Type="GhostableInLibrary"** to the File Tag, it is Mandatory and as your CAML is missing that you are not seeing it in the Library.

```
<File Path="Module_Indices\Indices\CSS\commonStyle.css" Url="Watson_Indices/CSS/commonStyle.css" Type="GhostableInLibrary" />
```